# calculator multiple values

Tags: java, awt

I am done with my calculator, thanks to the people here who helped me. Here what I have done:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleCalculator implements ActionListener
{
    double value1=0,value2=0,result=0;
    static  String command=null;
    int counter=0;

    // containers
    private Frame f;
    private Panel p1, p2, p3, p4,p5,p6;

    // components
    private Label l1, l2, l3;
    static private TextField tf1;
    private Button bAdd, bSub, bMul, bDiv, bClear,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0,bEqual;

     private static void value(String num)
        {
         if((tf1.getText()).equals("0"))
            tf1.setText(num);
          else
            tf1.setText(tf1.getText()+num);
         }
    public SimpleCalculator()
    {
        f = new Frame("My First GUI App");

        p1 = new Panel();
        p2 = new Panel();
        p3 = new Panel();
        p4 = new Panel();
        p5 = new Panel();
        p6 = new Panel();




        tf1 = new TextField(15);

        b1 = new Button("1");
        b2 = new Button("2");
        b3 = new Button("3");
        b4 = new Button("4");   
        b5 = new Button("5");
        b6 = new Button("6");
        b7 = new Button("7");
        b8 = new Button("8");
        b9 = new Button("9");
        b0 = new Button("0");
        bAdd = new Button("+");
        bSub = new Button("-");
        bMul = new Button("*");
        bDiv = new Button("/");
        bClear = new Button("C");
        bEqual = new Button("=");
    }
    public void launchFrame()
    {
        // use default layout manager of the Panel (FlowLayout)
        p1.add(tf1);


        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);

        p3.add(b4);
        p3.add(b5);
        p3.add(b6);

        p4.add(b7);
        p4.add(b8);
        p4.add(b9);

        p5.add(b0);

        p6.add(bAdd);
        p6.add(bSub);
        p6.add(bMul);
        p6.add(bDiv);
        p6.add(bClear);
        p6.add(bEqual);


        // change the layout manager of the Frame, 
        // use GridLayout(4, 1)
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));

        f.add(p1);
        f.add(p2);
        f.add(p3);
        f.add(p4);
        f.add(p5);
        f.add(p6);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        // register event handlers
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        b7.addActionListener(this);
        b8.addActionListener(this);
        b9.addActionListener(this);
        b0.addActionListener(this);
        bEqual.addActionListener(this);
        bAdd.addActionListener(this);
        bSub.addActionListener(this);
        bMul.addActionListener(this);
        bDiv.addActionListener(this);
        bClear.addActionListener(this);

        f.addWindowListener(new MyCloseButtonHandler());
    }
    // override the actionPerformed method
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        Object source = ae.getSource();

            if (source == b1)   
                value("1");
            else if (source == b2)
                value("2");
            else if (source == b3)
                value("3");
            else if (source == b4)
                value("4");
            else if (source == b5)
            value("5");
            else if (source == b6)
            value("6");
            else if (source == b7)
            value("7");
            else if (source == b8)
            value("8");
            else if (source == b9)
            value("9");
            else if (source == b0)
            value("0");
            else if(source== bAdd){
            value1=Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
            command="+";
            tf1.setText("");
            }
            else if(source==bSub){

            value1=Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
            command="-";
            tf1.setText("");

             }
             else if(source==bDiv){
             value1=Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
             command="/";
             tf1.setText("");
             }
             else if(source == bMul){
             value1=Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
             command="*";
             tf1.setText("");
             }
             else if(source ==bClear)
             tf1.setText("0");
            else if(source==bEqual){
            value2=Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
            if(command.equals("+"))
            result=value1+value2;
            else if(command.equals("-"))
            result=value1-value2;
            else if(command.equals("*"))
            result=value1*value2;
            else if(command.equals("/"))
            result=value1/value2;
            command="=";
            tf1.setText(""+result);
            }   

        }

    private class MyCloseButtonHandler extends WindowAdapter
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    double value1=0;
        SimpleCalculator sc = new SimpleCalculator();
        sc.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

The problem is that they can't perform operations continuously, like 1+2+3, I have tried adding the values each time I press an operation, but it gives me a wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Java's built-in Javascript parser for your calculator.

Comment: Is there a built-in JavaScript parser in Java?!

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing two values (value1 and value2), thus you can only do math with the two. Think of ways how you could store more values.

Comment: but the professor told us strictly that we are not allowed to use arrays, im out of idea. can you provide different ways?

Comment: @Gostores, if you're restricted to using certain API's/features from Java, better ask your professor or TA instead of asking here.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a tool like [jep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/) to parse the expression, unless this is something you have to hand code (like a school/college project)..
either ways it doesn't hurt to see the solution which exists.

Answer (score 0):

How about you display the result of the first 2 numbers (i.e. result, which works), and then when they hit another operand, you put `value1 = result` and `value2` be the next number. Then, once they hit equals again, you get `1+2+3`. You can then implement a clear button to set `result = 0`.